# Force waitkey() to do an operation {OpenCV}{PY}

Tags: opencv

I have a problem:
i create a small program that open the webcam and does face recognition.
Now i wanted to do this task: when a key( space ) is pressed, the program must go to phase 2(the face recognition). To do this, i used cv2.waitkey(). The main problem is that with my function when space is pressed, the program will go to phase 2 but just for few seconds (it goes in phase 2 just when space is pressed, and it stops when it is released).

Have you any advice?

i will give an example of what i mean:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   ##Load Cam
cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

while True:
   s, img = cam.read()
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   cv2.imshow(name, img)    
   k = cv2.waitKey(1)

   if k == 13: ## if return is pressed, on the screen will appear the text 'instruction',but when it 
               ## released the text disappear, and i don't want this...
       s, img = cam.read()
       gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
       cv2.putText(img,'instructions',(10,25), font, 0.7,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)

       cv2.imshow(name, img)
```

solution:

```
cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

while True:
   s, img = cam.read()
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   cv2.imshow(name, img)    
   k = cv2.waitKey(1)

   if k == 13: 
       break
while True:
   s, img = cam.read()
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   cv2.putText(img,'instructions',(10,25), font, 0.7,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)

   cv2.imshow(name, img)
```

Comment: Create a new variable named phase which is initialized with 1. Then if k == 13: phase = 2. In your loop then ask whether phase is 1 or 2 and do whatever you like in each of those phases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your conditional instructions are in a **loop** - they're run only while the condition is evaluated to **true**. To avoid this, consider **break**ing out of the loop and following further instructions.

```
 cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   ##Load Cam
 cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

 while True:
     s, img = cam.read()
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

     cv2.imshow(name, img)    
     k = cv2.waitKey(1)

     if k == 13:
         break

 s, img = cam.read()
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 cv2.putText(img,'instructions',(10,25), font, 0.7,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
 cv2.imshow(name, img)
 cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: ^^ final waitKey() missing ! ( else the last imshow() just won't )

Comment: waitKey is used to pause the execution for an (ms) interval and fetch a key. It is mostly used in loops therefore 'phase 2' does not imply any (<=> no loops involved upon fetching images)

Comment: .. also it is encapsulating the window's internal message-loop. without it, the window won't get updated. just try yourself !

Comment: Thanks you give me the hint for the solution!!

Comment: @berak Yes, you're correct. Didn't bare to check the aggregation methodology.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need some sort of 'timeout' ?

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   ##Load Cam
cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

timeout = 0
while True:
   s, img = cam.read()

   if timeout > 0:   # show message as long as timeout is valid
       cv2.putText(img,'instructions',(10,25), font, 0.7,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
       timeout = timeout - 1

   cv2.imshow(name, img)

   k = cv2.waitKey(1)    
   if k == 13:                
       timeout = 100 # show message for 100 frames
   if k == 27:                
       break         # bail out on 'escape'
```